# Is there a way to use a Finder hot key to open a folder in TextMate?

Tags: keyboard, textmate

I have setup a System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services item to allow me to use a hotkey to "Open in TextMate". It works fine on files, but does not work on folders.

If I Control+Click on the same folder, select "Services" from the pop-up menu and choose "Open in TextMate" the folder is opened as a project in TextMate. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Is there a way to setup a shortcut to have the same open folder as project behavior as the Control+Click method?

Comment: After seeing @Lri's answer I did a little more investigation. The keyboard shortcut did work for folder in any view *other than column view* in the Finder. I don't know if it's a bug or an intentional change, but I've seen multiple reports of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing @Lri's answer I discovered that my original service would work in the Finder as long as I wasn't in column view. Since that's the view that I use most of the time, I decided to see if I could get @Lir's basic solution working without the need for an external application. Here's what I did:

1. Open Automator and choose "Service" from the options of what to make.
2. Set "Service receives" to "no input" and "in" to "Finder.app".
3. Drop a "Run AppleScript" action onto the main window.
4. Drop the code @Lri provided into place so you end up with:

   ```
   on run {input, parameters}

       try
           tell application "Finder"
           open (get selection) using path to application "TextMate"
           end tell
       end try

       return input
   end run
   ```

   [image]
5. Save the action as "Open via TextMate".
6. Under "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" -> "Keyboard Shortcuts" -> "Services" -> "General" add my preferred shortcut to the "Open vie TextMate" item.

   [image]

This works in all my Finder views (including column view) for Mac OS X 10.7.3 and TextMate 1.5.10.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a bug with Finder. Services that receive folders as input don't seem to be listed in the Services menu when folders are selected (but it only applies to column view; they are listed in other view modes).

In any case, one alternative would be to just use an AppleScript without wrapping it as a service. You can give it an app-specific shortcut with [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/).

```
try
    tell application "Finder"
        open (get selection) using path to application "TextMate"
    end tell
end try
```

Comment: It does seem to be a bug in Lion's version of the Finder. The original shortcut I setup works in the other three Finder views that aren't column view.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do this with a piece of software called [Shortcuts](http://www.abracode.com/free/cmworkshop/).